# Mediawiki on turnkey with bluespice login causes redirect

Tags: mediawiki, bluespice

When i try to log into my Mediawiki website running with bluespice on turnkey the address i used to get to the site, e.g. example.wiki.com, becomes the IP address the site is running on. I do not want the site to do that and any help in getting to the bottom of this issue and fixing it would be appreciated, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out myself, what i had wrong was i had $wgServer set to the IP address of the website rather than the domain name i wanted to use, i got the answer from here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Login_required_twice:_first_login_reroutes_to_login_page/reply